# I can't access to my cakephp controller to use it into the url parameter jquery

Tags: jquery, url, cakephp-2.0, controller-action

when I try to use the controller/action in the jquery function for an url . I have a

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found

displayed in firebug . 
this how I am calling in  my jquery function .

```
 <?php $Url =Router::url(array('controller'=>'SessionModelsController','action'=>'transaction_ticker'),true); ?>
 function tick4(){
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
          url: '<?php echo $Url; ?>', ...
```

I have tried this too and it is the same problem .

```
>  var myBaseUrl = '<?php echo $this->Html->url('/'); ?>';
>
```

> ```
> function tick4(){
>     $.ajax({
>         type: "POST",
>         url: myBaseUrl + "SessionModelsController/transaction_ticker",
> ```

thank you.

EDIT :
the problem is resolved when I Have deleted

> Controller

from

> SessionModelsController

. and have used `SessionModels`

Comment: Have you tried logging the url using: `console.log(myBaseUrl + "SessionModelsController/transaction_ticker");` and verifying that it's being output properly?

Comment: the url is displayed perfectly :
 "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://******.com/project/SessionModelsController/transaction_ticker"